# Kendo Grid : Blank space in the end when you resize(reduce) any column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid and when i resize (reduce) any column, there is a white space shows up in the end of the grid. I have checked with the Kendo official samples and it seems like in some samples the shown behavior is in their samples.

I tried setting up width for header, cell content etc.. but its still shows some UI issues and i have multiple grids and i need a generic fix.

If its not an issue and a behavior then somebody please have a look at this and explain how to fix it.

I have added a normal screen shot and resized screenshot.

***normal***

[image]

***after resize***

[image]

**For testing it out, i have added a jsfiddle.,**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/49bhz2sk/
```

***html***

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <div id="fleetInfoGridDisplayDummy" class="" data-bind="autoHeightContainer:true"></div>
</div>
```

***script***

```
 $("#fleetInfoGridDisplayDummy").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                navigatable: true,
                selectable: true,
                sortable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                resizable: true,
                scrollable: { virtual: true },
                columnMenu: true, // Needed to hide and show columns.
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [{
                    template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
                    "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
                    "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
                    field: "ContactName",
                    title: "Contact Name",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "ContactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }, {
                    field: "CompanyName",
                    title: "Company Name"
                }, {
                    field: "Country",
                    width: 150
                }]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this in telerik forum and got a reply from the admin, here is how they suggested to resolve the issue. Posted here so that someone else can benefit from this.

Answer proposed by 'Drew B.' also works, i have seen that too in another post. The the code i posted is less cumbersome with minimal coding.

```
columnResize: function (e) {

                    // what is thead and tbody: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields
                    var grid = e.sender,
                        gridHeaderTable = grid.thead.parent(),
                        gridBodyTable = grid.tbody.parent();

                    // what is wrapper: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/fields/wrapper
                    // what is scrollbar(): https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/fields/support
                    if (gridBodyTable.width() < grid.wrapper.width() - kendo.support.scrollbar()) {

                      // remove the width style from the last VISIBLE column's col element
                      gridHeaderTable.find("> colgroup > col").last().width("");
                      gridBodyTable.find("> colgroup > col").last().width("");

                      // remove the width property from the last VISIBLE column's object
                      // https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/fields/columns
                      grid.columns[grid.columns.length - 1].width = "";

                      // remove the Grid tables' pixel width
                      gridHeaderTable.width("");
                      gridBodyTable.width("");
                    }

                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to various kendo sources, this is a mixture of [observed normal behavior (2013)](https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-columns-expand-even-when-column-widths-are-set#1RqR12Cr10yyA_JrsJgwDA), and [unexpected behavior (2017)](https://www.telerik.com/forums/bug-resizing-columns-with-specific-widths-less-than-grid-width#gcTYSROvZUmMRJ8RTeYl8Q).  Kendo does provide [a workaround](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-remove-trailing-space-resize) for this issue, as I suspect it isn't necessarily kendo related but more an HTML/Table feature.

```html
<style>
    .k-grid {
        width: 700px;
    }
</style>

<div id="grid1"></div>

<script>
    function getMasterColumnsWidth(tbl) {
        var result = 0;
        tbl.children("colgroup").find("col").not(":last").each(function (idx, element) {
            result += parseInt($(element).outerWidth() || 0, 10);
        });

        return result;
    }

    function adjustLastColumn() {
        var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
        var contentDiv = grid.wrapper.children(".k-grid-content");
        var masterHeaderTable = grid.thead.parent();
        var masterBodyTable = contentDiv.children("table");
        var gridDivWidth = contentDiv.width() - kendo.support.scrollbar();

        masterHeaderTable.width("");
        masterBodyTable.width("");

        var headerWidth = getMasterColumnsWidth(masterHeaderTable),
            lastHeaderColElement = grid.thead.parent().find("col").last(),
            lastDataColElement = grid.tbody.parent().children("colgroup").find("col").last(),
            delta = parseInt(gridDivWidth, 10) - parseInt(headerWidth, 10);

        if (delta > 0) {
            delta = Math.abs(delta);
            lastHeaderColElement.width(delta);
            lastDataColElement.width(delta);
        } else {
            lastHeaderColElement.width(0);
            lastDataColElement.width(0);
        }

        contentDiv.scrollLeft(contentDiv.scrollLeft() - 1);
        contentDiv.scrollLeft(contentDiv.scrollLeft() + 1);
    }


    $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
            },
            pageSize: 6,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 430,
        pageable: true,
        resizable: true,
        columnResize: adjustLastColumn,
        dataBound: adjustLastColumn,
        columns: [{
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name",
            width: "100px"
        }, {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name",
            width: "150px"
        }, {
            field: "Country",
            width: "100px"
        }, {
            field: "City",
            width: "100px"
        }, {
            field: "Title",
            width: "200px"
        }, {
            template: "&nbsp;"
        }]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the input. and yes, they have provided this as a workaround in their own forum (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-remove-trailing-space-resize),